# Beaglebone Black: Interaction between Device Tree and Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am currently developing a SPI Kernel Module for my Beaglebone Black (Debian Wheezy 2015-11-12, Kernel version 3.8.13-bone79). My kernel module can access (request_mem_region() => ioremap()) registers from the AM3358 processor (read/write) to manipulate the registers, to change the settings of the SPI0.
On the other side is my device tree, which can manipulate the pins of the SPI0.

Unfortunately, I´ve got Problems:

If I load my Device Tree first, and then my Kernel Module I get an message that I haven´t got permission to load my kernel module.

If I load my Module first and then my Device tree, all pinmuxes are allright, but the CLK of SPI0 is killed. Furthermore if I remove my module and free my allocated Memory (Registers, iounmap() => release_mem_region()) I get a 'Trying to free nonexistent resource' message.

You see, I am struggeling to understand the interaction between Device Tree and Kernel Module...

I would be extremely grateful, if someone could "push" me in the right direction... ;)

All the best

Flo

Comment: Is it academical interest? Otherwise I'm pretty sure that driver is present in mainline already.

Comment: Yes, I have to write about it in my Bachelor thesis...